# Reshaping a data frame that displays the first and last value of a variable to one that shows every value of that variable

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a tibble that looks like this

```
test01 <- tribble(~letter, ~firstRead, ~lastRead,
                  "A", 1, 3,
                  "B", 4, 7,
                  "C", 8, 8)
```

And I want to reshape it so that I have a row for every read, and that the letter for each is reported

```
test02 <- tribble(~letter, ~Read,
                  "A", 1,
                  "A", 2,
                  "A", 3,
                  "B", 4,
                  "B", 5,
                  "B", 6,
                  "B", 7,
                  "C", 8)
```

What is a simple way to convert from `test01` to `test02`?. Presumably I could run a for loop to fabricate a data frame for every line of this thing, but I feel like there must be a simpler way. Indeed, I'm sure this has been asked before but right now the language for even googling this problem escapes me. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to get the `seq` or (`:`) from 'firstRead' and 'lastRead' elementwise with `map2` into a `list` column and then `unnest` the `list` column

```
library(tidyverse)
test01 %>% 
   transmute(letter, Read = map2(firstRead, lastRead, `:`)) %>%
   unnest(Read)
# A tibble: 8 x 2
#  letter  Read
#  <chr>  <int>
#1 A          1
#2 A          2
#3 A          3
#4 B          4
#5 B          5
#6 B          6
#7 B          7
#8 C          8
```